# how can I store Image in android sdcard from todoit to another folder

Tags: android, sd-card

I have the number of images from the gallary.

I want to store the selected image into `mnt/sdcard/somefolder/image`

```
 IMAGE_PATH = getIntent().getStringExtra(bean.getImagePath());
    imgDisplayImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgDisplay);
    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(IMAGE_PATH);
    System.out.println("IMAGE PATH IN IMAGEDISPLAY CLASS"+ IMAGE_PATH);
    imgDisplayImage.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```

Comment: Do you want to store images in Sdcard?

Comment: yes i want to store image in my sdcard in Diese folder which i created.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually i can't understand.. 
taking pic from camera are set in gallery directly.

but if you have problem in your surface view then take this code...

```
View viewControl = controlInflater.inflate(R.layout.camara_view, null);
        LayoutParams layoutParamsControl = new LayoutParams(
                LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);
        this.addContentView(viewControl, layoutParamsControl);


    btnGallary = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnGallery);
    btnCaptureImage = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnCaptureImage);
    // Button buttonTakePicture = (Button)findViewById(R.id.takepicture);
    btnCaptureImage.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            camera.takePicture(myShutterCallback, myPictureCallback_RAW,
                    myPictureCallback_JPG);
        }
    });

    btnGallary.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
            // ImageGallery.class);
            // startActivity(intent);

            Intent intent = new Intent(
                    Intent.ACTION_PICK,
                    android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.INTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
            startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE);

        }
    });
```